# What is meant by structured objects in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Im just started reading PROLOG-Programming for Artifcial Intelligence and in the first couple of pages the author says:

"Prolog is especially suited for problems that involve objects - in particular structured objects - and relations between them."

Now my question is what is a structured object in this context. What are some examples of structured objects?

Comment: For example, `person(first_name(fred), last_name(smith))`. You can create compound terms that allow you to organize facts in a structured or hierarchical way. Prolog also supports lists, which are a form of structured object. And then of course you can have lists inside of compound terms, or lists of compound terms, etc... Such terms can all be expressed as a *functor* and arguments. Even a list `[1,2,3]` is really the functor `'.'`: `[1,2,3]` is equivalent to `'.'(1, '.'(2, '.'(3,[])))`.

Answer (score 2):

Examples of structured objects:

- **Terms**. Examples: `f(X,Y)`, `20` and `exp(12)`

and as a special case of terms:

- **Lists**. Examples: `[the,wheather,is,nice,today]` and `[hello,john,!]`

and as another special case of terms:

- **Rules** of the form "**if** Body **then** Head", written is `Head :- Body`.

Using such structured objects (*terms* are defined inductively), you can represent all kinds of knowledge, reasoning, and relationships between entities.